# Why does my TicTacToe code fail to detect is someone has won? Python 3

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I recently took it upon myself to try and code a TicTacToe board in order to test my understanding of the concepts I learned online. However, I encountered a few problems within my code and do not understand why it doesn't work as intended.

1. While attempting to get the code to print a winner, my code does not work as intended and does not choose a winner based on the values I have inputted. Sometimes the code runs and a winner is detected two turns after someone has already won, and sometimes it exits the code without a 5th move having even been played.
2. Below is the code I worked on. It includes insurance that you cannot input an X or an O in a position that has already been taken up and prints the Xs and Os where the players choose. I believe that the errors take place somewhere in the row(), column(), and diagonal() parts of the code.

```
 player = 0
 player_add = 1
 winner = None
 already_taken = []
 turns_taken = 0
 board = [
     "-", "-", "-",
     "-", "-", "-",
     "-", "-", "-"
]


def handle_turn(turn, turn_add):
    while turn % 2 == 0:
        position = int(input("Choose a position from 1-9 to add an \"X\": ")) - 1
        already_taken.append(position)
        board[position] = "X"
        turn += turn_add
        display_board()
        while already_taken.count(position) > 1:
            print("Position already taken.")
            board[position] = "O"
            display_board()
            already_taken.remove(position)
        turn += turn_add

    while turn % 2 == 1:
        position = int(input("Choose a position from 1-9 to add an \"O\": ")) - 1
        already_taken.append(position)
        board[position] = "O"
        turn += turn_add
        display_board()
        while already_taken.count(position) > 1:
            print("Position already taken.")
            board[position] = "X"
            display_board()
            already_taken.remove(position)
            turn += turn_add


def display_board():
    print(board[0] + "|" + board[1] + "|" + board[2])
    print(board[3] + "|" + board[4] + "|" + board[5])
    print(board[6] + "|" + board[7] + "|" + board[8])


def play_game():
    display_board()
    handle_turn(player, player_add)


def rows():
     global running
    if board[0] and board[1] and board[2] == board[0] and board[0] != "-":
        running = False
        return board[0]
    if board[3] and board[4] and board[5] == board[3] and board[3] != "-":
        running = False
        return board[3]
    if board[6] and board[7] and board[8] == board[6] and board[6] != "-":
        running = False
        return board[6]
    return


def columns():
    global running
    if board[0] and board[3] and board[6] == board[0] and board[0] != "-":
        running = False
        return board[0]
    if board[1] and board[4] and board[7] == board[1] and board[1] != "-":
        running = False
        return board[3]
    if board[2] and board[5] and board[8] == board[2] and board[2] != "-":
        running = False
        return board[6]
    return


def diagonals():
    global running
    if board[0] and board[4] and board[8] == board[0] and board[0] != "-":
        running = False
        return board[0]
    if board[2] and board[4] and board[6] == board[2] and board[2] != "-":
        running = False
        return board[3]
    return


def check_if_win():
    global winner
    # Rows
    row_winner = rows()
    # Columns
    column_winner = columns()
    # Diagonals
    diagonal_winner = diagonals()
    if row_winner:
        winner = row_winner
    elif column_winner:
        winner = column_winner
    elif diagonal_winner:
        winner = diagonal_winner
    else:
        winner = None


def check_if_game_over():
    check_if_win()


running = True
while running:
    play_game()
    check_if_game_over()
if winner == "X":
    print("Player " + str(winner) + " has won!")
elif winner == "O":
    print("Player " + str(winner) + " has won!")
elif winner is None:
    print("Whoops! Looks like you both loose.")
```

'''

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, but you made a typo:

```
if board[0] and board[3] and board[6] == board[0] and board[0] != "-":
```

This should be:

```
if board[0] == board[3] and board[6] == board[0] and board[0] != "-":
```

I would say, if you fix all of those. It may work - at least a little bit better.
*Hope this taught you not to copy-paste code too much, as you can easily copy the same mistake over and over again.*

So, what happened? Well, if you have `if(board[0] and board[3])` like you did, it checks if `board[0]` evaluates to true and the same for `board[3]`. The way `true` and `false` is implemented is that `false = 0`, and `true` is just the opposite of false: `true = !false`. So, what you were checking for was pretty much, "is board[0] zero?" No, so that is `true`. So, no wonder that you were confused.